# Select only post id and meta value with WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query

I'm developing a simple rank plugin, which allows visitors to like the posts and also shows the **total like scores** for each tag in the plugin's admin page. I need both post IDs (in order to reach the tag data of them) and like values.

This is my query at the moment:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_Like',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But this query returns the complete post object, it's not efficient for the memory. I only need `_Like` value and the `post_id`. Is there a better query for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own MySQL query to achieve this. You may use PHP builtin functions or WPDB which is a MySQL wrapped used by WordPress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb